# How to update array of documents in mongodb?

Tags: arrays, angularjs, mongodb, express

I have AdminGroupOperation model which looks like this:

```
var AdminGroupOperation = new mongoose.Schema({
    module    : String,
    adminGroup: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'AdminGroup'},
    operations: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Operation'}],

    recycled: Number
});
```

and my Operation model which looks like this:

```
var Operation = new mongoose.Schema({
    name : String,
    value: Boolean,


    recycled: Number
});
```

How can I update operations array in AdminGroupOperations model? In my api I have something like this but this wont work..

```
exports.update = function (req, res, next) {
    var data = req.body;

    AdminGroupOperation.findByIdAndUpdate({"_id": req.params.id}, {
            module    : data.module,
            adminGroup: data.adminGroup._id,
            operations: data.$.operations_id
        },
        {new: true},

        function (err, secoperation) {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }
            secoperation.save(function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    return next(err);
                }
            });

            res.json({'status': 'updated', 'ID': req.params.id});
        })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use id without request, I mean :

```
 AdminGroupOperation.findByIdAndUpdate req.params.id, { $set:{
        module    : data.module,
        adminGroup: data.adminGroup._id,
        operations: data.$.operations_id
    }}, {new: true},

    function (err, secoperation) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        secoperation.save(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }
        });

        res.json({'status': 'updated', 'ID': req.params.id});
    })
  };
```

I am not sure for the option : {new : true}, or you can simply use update with using the request to find with the ID

Comment: So my query now looks like:     `AdminGroupOperation.findByIdAndUpdate(data._id,
        {
            "$set": {
                "module"      : data.module,
                "adminGroup"  : data.adminGroup._id,
                "operations.$": data.operations
            }
        }`
but this wont work

Comment: try with update request [link] http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/updating-documents.html

Comment: So I still didn't get it to work. My code so far is `AdminGroupOperation.findOne({'_id': req.body._id})
        .populate('operations')
        .exec(function (err, record) {
            for (var i = 0; i < record.operations.length; i++) {
                var currentRecord = record.operations[i],
                    currentParam  = req.body.operations[i];

                currentRecord.value = currentParam.value;
            }

            record.markModified('operations');
            record.save()
        }); `